# Error: Property does not exist on type 'Registration'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am developing in JavaScript and Typescript.  I have the function below that checks an array for duplicates but I am getting an error and I'm not sure exactly how to resolve.  Below is the error and an excerpt of the code.

**Error: Property 'toLocaleLowerCase' does not exist on type 'Registration'.ts(2339)**

***Registration.ts***

```
  export interface Registration {
   address: string;
   comment?: string;
   fullname?: string;
  }
```

**JS file**

```
const nameAlreadyExist = (name: any): void => {
    const nameExist = filteredRegistrationName.value.findIndex((registrationName) => 
       registrationName.fullname.toLocaleLowerCase() === name.toLocaleLowerCase());
 
    nameExist != -1 ? (existNameError.value = true) : (existNameError.value = false);
   };
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what it means - it doesn't exist on your `Registration` type. `toLocaleLowerCase()` only exists on type `string` - so unless you can map the `Registration` type to a `string`, it won't work. I see that `Registration.fullname` is a string, but it is also optional - meaning that it is possibly undefined, which could also be throwing the error.

Comment: AHHH...I see now.  How do I fix that before making the comparison? The error is actually on 'registrationName.fullname.toLocaleLowerCase()'.

Comment: the fullname is nullable, maybe you're calling this function on a null value. You can try to call **registrationName.fullname?.toLocaleLowerCase()**

Comment: @OLA what @Alexandre Heinen said, the TypeScript `?` is meant to prevent errors relating to `undefined` or `null`. Similar to how appending `!` after a member tells TypeScript that this value is possibly null and to disregard it if it is.